# Fast SPI reading

Tags: spi

I am trying to read MCP3201 with 44100 samples per second.  The chip has top clock frequency of 1Mhz, which should be sufficient for 62500 two-byte samples per second.

```
sampnumb = 44100

spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,0)
spi.max_speed_hz = 125000000

for i in range(sampnumb):
    dat = spi.xfer2([0x00, 0x00])
```

It actually takes almost 2s to read as many samples.  Using 976000 for max_speed_hz makes it even slower.

Are there any ways to make sampling faster in Python?  If not, is this possible to achieve fast sampling any other way?

Answer (score 2):

You need to write your software in another language to achieve the speed you are after.

The obvious choice is C.

Comment: integrate top level python calls into low level c calls with cython.  don't do a big for loop in python- instead loop in c but tell c the number to loop via python.

Comment: @Abel I intend to use `ctypes` since I already have experience with that.

Comment: With a simple C script (`ioctl(fd_spi, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(1), &spi);`  `spi.rx_buf = spi.rx_buf + 2;`) I could get about 15k sampling.  Unfortunately sampling is not very consistent, which means that FFT of the sound is rather noisy.  Any ideas for improvement?

Comment: Use pigpio.  Use a faster Pi (you appear to be using an old one).

Comment: You are doing something wrong if you are getting slower rates in C compared to Python.  Have you set the SPI bit rate in your C code?

Comment: I am using RPi4 and sampling is faster with C.  I am using `spi.delay_usecs = 0;` `spi.speed_hz = frequency;` `spi.bits_per_word = 8;`

Comment: Your question says the Python is reading 44100 samples in 2 seconds.  That is 22k.  More than the 15k from your C.